# Does War Ring maximize all critical damage dice or only the dice it adds itself?

Tags: dnd-4e, magic-items

The item War Ring has this rules text:

> War Ring
>
> Level 16 Uncommon
>
> *This steel band, emblazoned with a stylized
> sword, makes your attacks even more lethal.*
>
> Ring Slot        45,000 gp
>
> **Property:** When you score a critical hit, deal 1 extra die of critical
> hit damage, based on the weapon or implement you wield. If your weapon
> or implement deals no extra damage when you score a critical hit, deal
> an extra 1d6 damage when you score a critical hit.
>
> **Power  Daily (Free
> Action):** Use this power when you score a critical hit with a weapon or
> implement. Add 2 extra dice of critical hit damage based on the weapon
> or implement. If your weapon or implement deals no extra damage when
> you score a critical hit, deal an extra 2d6 damage when you score a
> critical hit. If you've reached at least one milestone today, instead
> of rolling the extra dice of critical hit damage, deal extra damage
> equal to the maximum value of those dice.

If I have reached at least one milestone, does the daily power maximize only the 2 dice from the daily power, all 3 dice from the War Ring, or all critical damage extra dice, including those from the weapon itself?

Comment: It's definitely not option 3, since it specifically refers to "the extra dice," i.e. the extra dice from the ring. Leaning towards 1, but not certain enough to make an answer out of it.

Comment: It may be all extra critical dice as well. They are also called "extra dice" in the rules when explaining critical hits. That is a really good question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Going off of how the Power is worded, I'm going to lean towards the line being more internal then anything.

> Power Daily (Free Action): Use this power when you score a critical
>   hit with a weapon or implement. Add 2 extra dice of critical hit
>   damage based on the weapon or implement.

Gives you the extra dice that your question would apply to.

> If your weapon or implement deals no extra damage when you score a
>   critical hit, deal an extra 2d6 damage when you score a critical hit.

Refers to a weapon or implement that, by some quality or reason, is unable to perform a critical at all.

> If you've reached at least one milestone today, instead of rolling the
>   extra dice of critical hit damage, deal extra damage equal to the
>   maximum value of those dice.

After reaching the milestone, this clause takes effect. Instead of rolling the extra dice of C.H.D (noted above in the power as 2 extra dice as per weapon), you would instead maximize those 2 dice of damage given by this power. This power effects only the dice given by the power, as otherwise it may include a line such as:

> ...deal extra damage equal to the maximum value of all critical hit damage dice for this attack.

In this case, it's my assumption/belief that the power is additive to the War Ring's property, however the extra dice that are maximized are just the ones inclusive to the Daily Power.